# Behave BDD Tests - End threads/nodes at end of test

Tags: python, multithreading, bdd, python-behave

I have created a client and server that run on separate threads upon construction, using the threading module.

I'm trying to run behave BDD tests, but I'm having difficulty ending the threads properly at the end of the test.

My current solution is

```
@given(u'Client and server are ran concurrently')
def step_imp(context):
    client = cl.Client()
    server= srv.Server()
    server.start()
    client.start()
    
    # End client-server after some time
    time.sleep(5)
    server.terminate()
    client.terminate()

@when(Something happens')
def step_imp(context):
  #some code

@then(u'Something happens')
def step_imp(context):
  #some code
```

Ideally, I could move the end client-server code to its own then block, like so:

```
@then(u'The client-server dies after some time.')
def step_imp(context):
    time.sleep(5)
    server.terminate()
    client.terminate()
```

But I've found little success in doing so. Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried putting the `terminate` functions in the after_x (scenario/feature/all) hook functions in `environment.py`?

Comment: or use fixtures as the way of controlled setup/teardown of your scenarios: [behave fixtures](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#fixtures)